# .NET Datamodel Regex always showing error message

Tags: c#, .net, regex

My regex is as follows:

```
"^[a-zA-Z](?![_.@-])[a-zA-Z0-9@-_.]+(?<![_@.-])$"
```

The entire line of code is:

```
   [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z](?![_.@-])[a-zA-Z0-9@-_.]+(?<![_@.-])$", ErrorMessage = "Username must contain alphanumeric, '@', '.', '-', or '_' only ")]
```

I have tested this Regex out online, and it works just as I want it too. However, on the .NET site it always displays the error message, even if the string is correct

This regex is for username validation and I want it to:

- start off with a letter (case insensitive)
- contain alphanumeric, @, -, _, and . only (does not have to contain
  those things but those are the valid characters
- not have @, -, _, or    . at the beginning or end of the string

Comment: This is simpler : "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9@-_.]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$"

Comment: That regex is much better, but the error message still always pops up even if the string is valid

Comment: Are you sure that `@-_` does what you think it does?

Comment: Your regex allows `[ \ ] ^`, use `"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9@_.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$"`

Comment: Please add your error message to your question, Hope to make more sense ;).

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply :
`"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9@-_.]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$"`

Comment: That regex is much better, but the error message still always pops up even if the string is valid

Comment: @pbokey for which input?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub what do you mean for which input

Comment: `the error message still always pops up even if the string is valid` what's the value of the valid string?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub test@test.com

Comment: @pbokey both regexes are correct, we'll need more context

Answer (score 0):

You should put the "-" as the first character in the character range, because otherwise `@-_` means: all the characters in the range "@" ... "_" (@ThomasAyoub gave the hint). And as @CCH already said, you can simplify the expression

```
^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9@_.]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
          ^
          Note the "-" here
```

This expresssion also requires at least 2 charaters which is a resonable limitation of user names